# RSK correspondence

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux, robinson-schensted-knuth

Up to now, what are the difference ways we know to define RSK correspondence? I already know:

1. By insertion and recording tableau.
2. Ball construction or Viennot's geometric construction.
3. Growth diagram proposed by Sergey Fomin.

Do you know other models?

Comment: There is a very enlightening description of RSK in terms of piecewise-linear maps that goes back to Igor Pak: https://eudml.org/doc/121696

Comment: See also the presentation of Robin Sulzgruber: https://dx.doi.org/10.4310/JOC.2020.v11.n2.a3

Comment: There is also a direct connection of RSK to important topics in representation theory like Hecke algebras, Kazhdan-Lusztig theory, Springer fibers, etc. and that perspective is probably the most 'canonical'. But it sounds like you are interested in combinatorial constructions.

Comment: Dear Sam, thank you so much for your references. it is very good if you can tell me more about the connection of RSK correspondence to important topic in representation theory. I just know a litter bit about RSK. Another connection will provide new point of view.

Comment: Do you know about the relation between KL cells and Knuth equivalence? See e.g. arxiv.org/abs/math/9910117 for the basics along these lines.

Comment: Dear Sam, it is new for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Greene's theorem describes the shape of the insertion tableau in terms of unions of increasing subsequences of the permutation $w=a_1\cdots a_n$. Thus we can build up the insertion tableau $P(w)$ one step at a time by applying Greene's theorem to the subpermutations (subsequences) of $w$ consisting of the numbers $1,2,\dots,i$. We can similarly compute the recording tableau $Q(w)$ since $Q(w)=P(w^{-1})$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Stanley, thank you so much for your comment. This is a very new point of view. Thank you so much!

Comment: Dear Prof. Stanley, I am reading 

- Your book: "Enumerative combinatorics volume 2" and 
- The article by Prof. Sergey Fomin "Generalized Robinson-Schensted-Knuth correspondence" 

to understand the RSK correspondence by growth graph for two-rowed array in lexicographic order. But it seems difficult for me to understand the article of Prof. Fomin since there is no example. I find an example in your book, but it just for the only permutation. 

For example, to compute pair $(P,Q)$ of $w=(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5// 2,3,1,1,3,4,5,1)$.

Could you give me some examples or better references!

Comment: @KhanhNguyen: we can reduce the case of two-rowed arrays to permutations by standardization. See the end of Section 7.11 of my book. Growth diagrams are "compatible" with standardization, so growth diagrams for two-rowed arrays reduce to the case of permutations.

Comment: Dear Prof. Stanley, I see it, page 321. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, slightly edited, is the first paragraph of Steinberg's paper, [An occurrence of the Robinson–Schensted correspondence](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(88)90177-9).

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over an infinite field, $\mathscr F$ the flag manifold of $V$, $u$ a unipotent transformation of $V$, and $\lambda$ the type of $u$, a partition of $n$ whose parts are the sizes of the Jordan blocks for $u$. … The components of $\mathscr F_u$, the variety of flags fixed by $u$, correspond naturally to the standard tableaux of shape $\lambda$. The purpose of this note is to show that the "relative position" of any two components of $\mathscr F_u$ (in general an element of the Weyl group, in the present case an element of $S_n$) is given, in terms of the corresponding tableaux, by the Robinson–Schensted correspondence.

Comment: Thanks Timothy!